# Difference between OpenSSH server and Apache server?

Tags: webserver, openssh, apache2.4

Is there any difference between OpenSSH Server and Apache Server?

Backstroy:
I need a web-server with a database.
While installing Ubuntu Server, I chose an option to install OpenSSH Server as well as PostgreSQL database. If I want Apache Server, do I need to uninstall OpenSSH Server and then install Apache Server or they somehow complement each other?

What are definite things to consider when running a server?

It's my first server by the way.

Comment: They are two different things. OpenSSH is an SSH server, Apache is a Web server.

Comment: @Pilot6-Is it OK, if I just install Apache server to the same machine as well and use them together? And if I want to access Apache server, can I do it through another computer using ssh?

Comment: @Name I'm pretty sure if you don't mix the assigned ports for the two, then you can have both running.

Comment: You can use them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default OpenSSH Server uses port 22 and Apache Webserver (with default config) uses ports 80 and 443
So you can safely install them alongside each other.

Packages in general are installed, updated or removed via `aptitude` or `apt-get`

[apt-get in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

[Aptitude in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html)

To install Apache by the way you can enter `sudo apt-get install apache2`

If this server should be reachable from the internet you should consider installing UFW ([UncomplicatedFirewall in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall)), which is a firewall and configuring it to allow only ssh and http/s

Also keep your packages up to date with

```
# This updates the package lists
sudo apt-get update
# This actually upgrades packages if new versions are found
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And if you want to install held back updates use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @MarkKirby this should be better right?

Comment: Yep, just a few links for detail was all it needed :)

Comment: @levanth - As you mentioned ports, I googled it to find some more information. I read an article suggesting changing those default port values for security reasons. Is it wise to do so and does it really help?

Comment: @Name if you change your port for ssh you can avoid most of the ssh-attacks against your server (because most people/bots try port 22) so this would be a good decision.
If you change the Port from your WebServer you have to keep in mind that you need to add `:<newport>` when you try to visit your webserver.


Webserver with normal ports `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com`

Webserver with changed ports (8090 for http 8190 for https as example): `http://www.example.com:8090` and `https://www.example.com:8190`